# Explain Nyström Method

Tags: numerical-methods, integral-equations

To solve an integral equation numerically, we can apply Nyström's method.
Therefor we approximate the integral operator

$(A\varphi)(x) := \int \limits_G K(x,y)\varphi(y)dy,\; x \in G$

by a sequence of numerical integration operators.

$(A_n\varphi)(x) := \sum \limits_{k=1}^n \alpha_k^{(n)}K(x,x_k^{(n)})\varphi(x_k^{(n)}),\; x\in G$

Hence, the solution to the integral equation

$\varphi - A\varphi=f$

is approximated by the solution of

$\varphi_n - A_n \varphi_n = f$

as for exampled described in Rainer Kress' Linear Integral Equations on p. 201.

Apparently, this reduces to solving a finite-dimensional linear system.

However, I fail to see, where this takes place.

Assuming the Kernel
$K(x,y) = (x+1)e^{-x*y}/2$
and the function
$f(x) = e^{-x}+1/2*(e^{-x-1}-1)$

can someone please show me, step by step, how this is done, given the IEQ

$\varphi(x)-\int \limits_0^1K(x,y)\varphi(y)dy=f(x)$, with exact solution $\varphi(x)=e^{-x}$

Therefore let's discretize the interval [0,1] with $x_i$ in {0, 1/3, 2/3, 1} (so $n=4$).

I then get:

$\varphi_4 - A_4 \varphi_4 = f$, that is

$\varphi_4 - \sum \limits_{k=1}^{4}\alpha_k (x+1)e^{-x*x_k^{(4)}}/2\varphi(x_k^{(4)})=e^{-x}+1/2*(e^{-x-1}-1)$

But here, I don't know how to continue.

**UPDATE**
So this yields

$\varphi_4(x) = f(x) + \sum \limits_{k=1}^4 \alpha_k K(x, x_k) \varphi(x_k)$
$\varphi_4(x) = e^{-x}+1/2*(e^{-x-1}-1) + \alpha_1 K(x, 0) * \varphi(0) + \alpha_2 K(x, 1/3) * \varphi(1/3) + \alpha_3 K(x, 2/3) \varphi(2/3) + \alpha_4 K(x, 1) * \varphi(1)$

I'm certain this is false, as I can't see how to find my solution. Where did I do my mistake?

Comment: Once you evaluate $K$ and $f$ at all the relevant points, you just have an ordinary linear system to be solved by e.g. Gaussian elimination.

Comment: But here I have to evaluate $\varphi$ at $x_k$, don't I?

Comment: $\varphi$ is unknown; $\varphi(x_k)$ are unknown numbers $\varphi_k$ to be determined by solving the system.

Comment: But how can I solve it, when I have $\alpha_k$ and $\varphi_k$ unknown? I only see 4 equations here, but that would be 8 unknowns

Comment: $\alpha_k^{(n)}$ are not unknown, they are quadrature weights.

Comment: Ah yes, you're right. I must take my earlier claim back. I don't see 4 equations. In fact I only see one equation, I'll write it  in the OP. I'm sure I'm mistaken here, though, because I obviously can't solve it this way.

Comment: No, it's four equations, one for each value of $f$.

Comment: So it is $f(x_k)$, not $f(x)$?

Comment: Yes, one equation for each x.